# How do I make an XGET request with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to make the following query with jQuery only:

```
curl -XGET "https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/55-11-5525-6325?Type=carrier&Type=caller-name" -u "{AccountSid}:{AuthToken}"
```

So far I have:

```
$.get("https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/" + number + "?Type=carrier", function (data) {
    callback(data);
});
```

But how do I include the `-u` data?

Comment: you wouldn't want to...would expose your credentials in browser. Also you need token before you can send it

Comment: [`-X` just lets you specify the method.](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-X) So doing `-XGET` is the same as doing a GET request, which is actually the default for `curl`.

Comment: @MikeC OP is asking how to send the credentials

Comment: @epascarello Maybe but the title is "How do I make an XGET request with jQuery?"

Comment: And the last line is _"But how do I include the -u data?"_  and clearly the OP used jQuery's get()